# How to drop one or multiple columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-down-menu

To Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame or Drop one or more than one column from a DataFrame can be achieved in multiple ways.

Create a simple Dataframe with dictionary of lists, say column names are A, B, C, D, E. In this article, we will cover 6 different methods to delete some columns from Pandas DataFrame.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TafHr.png)

Comment: You don't have a question in your question, or did you just share a stage of your learning?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the next code:

```
df.drop(['column_name', 'column_name2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```